# How to use ignore padding on an element in a div

Tags: css, positioning, padding

I have text and `<hr>` alternating vertically in a div and I added `padding-left` to the div but I don't want the horizontal rule between the words to be affected by the padding.

Is there a way exclude them?

```
.menuoptions {
    height:30px;
    width:225px;
    color:#666;
    line-height:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

I tried `.menuoptions hr {...}` and adding negative padding, but to not much surprise, it didn't work.

Example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AD4zs/)

Comment: You really should be using a proper menu `ul/li` structure and then use `border-bottom`

Comment: I might give that a go and see how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't exclude them per se, and negative padding is a no-no, but you can use negative margins on the `<hr>`

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AD4zs/5/)

Comment: Ahh I was so close! why is it ok for negative margins but not padding?

Comment: Simply because of the nature of the box model; padding pushes content further inside the box, away from the inner edge (essentially a part of the box itself), while margin pushes other content around the box away from the outer edge. If you think about it like that, negative padding makes no sense at all :) For more info on the box model you can check out this article at [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/).

Comment: More on [negative margins specifically](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/), for future reference

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a negative `margin-left`

```
.menuoptions hr {
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AD4zs/4/)

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have not made a reset of the custom attributes. Like `<p>`, `<input>`, etc. by default have some padding and margin and when you add an attribute, it populates accordingly.

In case of such inconsistencies across browsers, I suggest you to use a CSS Reset probably [Eric Mayer Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

This will normalize all your discrepancies and shall render your page with uniform consistencies across all browsers.

**The Code:**

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I will make sure to use this in the future

Comment: still does not answer the question though

Comment: An answer will be a patch to what the OP wants, as CSS reset will solve his issues. - @epoch

Answer (score 0):

```
.menuoptions hr {
 margin-left:-10px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use a `ul`, which would be the correct way to do this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Firewalls</li>
    <li class="sep"></li>
    <li>Security In Education</li>
    <li class="sep"></li>
    <li>SSL VPN Encryption</li>
    <li class="sep"></li>
    <li>Wireless Access Points</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#666;
    font-weight:bold;
    width: 300px;
}
ul > li {
    padding:5px;
}
ul > li.sep {
    height:1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding:0;
}
```

The **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AD4zs/7/)**